# Take screenshot in RSelenium

Tags: r, macos, screenshot, screen-scraping, rselenium

I have a Mac.

When I run the following code in R:

```
library(RSelenium)
 
 driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome"))
 remDr <- driver[["client"]]
  
 remDr$open()
 remDr$navigate("http://goskills.com")
  b64out <- remDr$screenshot()
  writeBin(base64Decode(b64out, "raw"), 'startpage.png')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in base64Decode(b64out, "raw") : 
  could not find function "base64Decode"
```

I have RSelenium version ‘1.7.7’

Comment: Using `processx::base64_decode` ?

Comment: I get the same error when running on Windows 10

Comment: Using the link that was provided, along with installing the magick package, I was able to get it to work.  Thanks for your help!